# Page 276 of Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris; wrong parameter count?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, complex-geometry

The following is taken from page $276$ of *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris:

> Now let $S$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g\ge 3$. By our last result, if $S$ has any automorphism at all, it has an automorphism $\varphi$ of prime order $p$. Let $S'$ be the quotient of $S$ by the group of automorphisms $\{ \varphi^l \} $, and $g'$ the genus of $S'$. Since a fixed point of any power $\varphi^i$ of $\varphi$ is a fixed point of $\varphi$, the branch locus of the quotient map $\pi: S\to S'$ consists simply of a certain number $k$ of $(p-1)$-fold branch points; and to specify the surface upto a finite number of choices we simply have to specify the surface $S'$ together with $k$ points on $S'$. This is a total of $3g'+k+3$ parameters; but now by Riemann-Hurwitz,
>
> $$2g-2 = p(2g'-2)+k(p-1),$$
>
> i.e.,
>
> $$k=\frac{2g-2-p(2g'-2)}{p-1}=\frac{2g-2pg'}{p-1}+2.$$
>
> Thus we have at most
>
> $$3g'+\frac{2g-2pg'}{p-1}-1$$
>
> parameters for $S$;

This is what I don't understand. Shouldn't it be $3g'+k-3$, in order for the upper bound of $3g'+\frac{2g-2pg'}{p-1}-1$ to take place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If $S'$ is a surface with genus $g' \geq 2$, then it is 'described' by $3g' - 3$ parameters (i.e. the moduli space of genus $g'$ curves has dimension $3g' - 3$). If we include the additional $k$ parameters used to describe the position of the $k$ branch points, we have a total of $3g' - 3 + k$ parameters, not $3g' + 3 + k$.

With this correct parameter count, we obtain the desired expression:

$$3g' - 3 + k = 3g' - 3 + \frac{2g - 2pg'}{p-1} + 2 = 3g' + \frac{2g-2pg'}{p-1} - 1.$$